# O Código gerado pela GUI builder do netbeans afeta desempenho da aplicação?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

O Netbeans possui uma ferramenta de criação de interface com o usuário usando o [**swing**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), que facilita bastante o desenvolvimento de aplicações desktops, porém, a ferramenta parece criar inúmeras linhas de código mesmo para algo simples muitas vezes.

Exemplo:

Esse código:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package swingTests;

/**
 *
 * @author diego.felipe
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 149, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(42, 42, 42))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addContainerGap(204, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

É gerado quando se faz uma interface como essa da figura, com apenas 5 elementos(`JFrame` propriamente dito, um `JTextField`, um `JLabel` e o `Jpanel` envolvendo eles).

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Gostaria de saber se o fato de se criar GUI's usando a ferramenta, em comparação a programar uma interface totalmente via código, pode afetar o desempenho da aplicação em si, por causa desse "código sujo" gerado pela ferramenta.

Comment: Lembrando que praticamente todo esse "código gerado" pode ser configurado nas preferências do IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso depende de gosto, até mesmo a pergunta pode ser interpretada como principalmente baseada em opiniões.

Mas pense comigo: se o Netbeans faz todo o trabalho de criar o código da interface para você, por que você faria isso tudo na mão? Veja bem, isso não faria sentido nenhum, você vai levar **muito** tempo fazendo tudo na mão, quando tem uma ferramenta que faz tudo em alguns segundos/minutos.

Não adianta tentar ser **o grande programador** que faz tudo na mão, quando existem dezenas de ferramentas que podem te ajudar a otimizar seu tempo, deixando com que você se preocupe somente com que é realmente necessário. E isso não vale só para interface gráfica, vale para tudo aquilo que você puder otimizar com a ajuda de alguma ferramenta (tendo bom senso e sabendo usá-la, claro).

Quanto a desempenho eu não tenho certeza se um é melhor que o outro, só testando para saber. Mas tenho a impressão de que não faz diferença nenhuma criar tudo na mão ou deixar que o Netbeans crie por você. Se fizer alguma diferença, deve ser algo mínimo, imperceptível e que (provavelmente) você não deva se preocupar, pelo menos não tão cedo.